# How to run java jar which includes python file using command promt

Tags: java, python

I am calling .py file from my Java class. I used pyDev python interpreter from marketplace in eclipse. When I am calling from java main method in eclipse, I am able to get output from .py file.
Now I have created jar file of that maven project and trying to execute jar using command prompt. But I am not getting results from .py file.
How should I get that output.

Comment: “But I am not getting results from .py file.”  We need more information than that.  What *are* you seeing?  If there is an exception, edit your question and include the full stack trace.

Comment: And you should show us the relevant part of your code.